# Trying to skip duplicate values in Where for Laravel

Tags: mysql, database, laravel-5

I want to display all the teams for a year only once in Laravel. I can't get the distinct() to work because I'm not using a select(). How do I skip repeating values in where() or how do I include a variable with an array for select? I have also tried messing with "array_unique".

```
public function showyear($id)
{
    $matchThese = [ 'homeWin' => '1', 'year'=>'2006'];

    $wins = GameData::where($matchThese)->distinct()->orderBy('team','asc')->get();

    $gamedatas = GameData::findOrFail($id);

    return view('games/showyear', compact('gamedatas', 'wins'));
}
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` is precisely what you should be using here.  I recommend writing out the raw MySQL first, then trying to translate it to Laravel.

Comment: Is the distinct I am using in my $wins variable placed incorrectly?... I have also tried this:  $wins = GameData::select()->where('homeWin', '1')->where('year', '2006')->distinct()->orderBy('team', 'asc')->get(); but to no avail. I will try to get my desired results in MySQL though. Thanks.

Comment: Do I need to be able to use select() to get distinct? If so, how do I pass in multiple conditions for the select() to find?

Comment: I don't know enough Laravel to bang out an answer for you, but first you really need to write the MySQL query.  Without that, you're going to be groping around in the wrong direction.

Comment: You may answer your own question below if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

You were right... once I got it working in mysql, it made a lot more sense. I needed to pass my the column i wanted in my select like so:

```
  $wins = GameData::select('team')->where('homeWin', '1')->where('year', 
 '2006')->distinct()->orderBy('team', 'asc')->get();
```